# Emacs statusbar access keyboard shortcut

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, statusbar

In terminal mode, I can access emacs menu bar using <kbd>F10</kbd> key, but I am wondering how can I access status bar. For example if I want to access some function of minor mode.

Comment: The question is unclear, to me at least. What do you mean by "status bar"? Do you mean mode-line? minibuffer/echo-area? And what do you mean by "access some function of minor mode"?

Comment: Yes Drew, is it possible in terminal mode?